# Sam not encoding request body while being locally invoked

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

The event body is not getting encoded while invoking `sam local start-api` and sending a multipart request but it's being encoded in the cloud. So, I'd like to have the same behavior in my local environment.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Create the **Hello World** project provided by `sam init`
2. Add a post method

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post
            ContentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY # This is not doing the magic as I was expecting
            BinaryMediaTypes:
              - "*/*"
              - multipart/form-data
```

3. Return the isBase64Encoded in the handler.

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        // const ret = await axios(url);
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                message: event.isBase64Encoded,
                // location: ret.data.trim()
            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    return response
};
```

4. Perform the HTTP request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello' \
--header 'saa: csv/csv-file' \
--form 'foo=@/home/user/csv-file.csv'
```

5. The response is always the same:

```
{
    "message": false
}
```

I've tried to use the proxy integration but it didn't work.

My **workaround** is to have something like this in the handler:

```
const csvString = event.isBase64Encoded ? Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64').toString('utf-8') : event.body;
```

Comment: Your `lambdaHandler` is hardcoded to return `{"message": false}`.  If you want that to be different modify the code.

Comment: That's not true, the function is returning `message: event.isBase64Encoded` .

Comment: No.  try running `JSON.stringify({message: event.isBase64Encoded})` in a console.log if you don t believe it